# How to create a map with sum of all specific objects?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have an object:

```
class Sample
{
    String currency;
    String amount;
}
```

I want an output map with sum of all objects of a specific currency.

Example-

- INR 40
- USD 80
- EUR 20

Pointer. I have been working with the following code but its not working as I expected. You can use this code as reference:

```
Map<String, Double> finalResult = samples
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Sample::getCurrency,
                e -> e.getAmount()
                      .stream()
                      .sum()));
```

Comment: Not sure what your actual question is. "Possible solution" sounds like you already have your answer? If you are facing issues, please add them to the question.

Comment: @Marvin : It is more of a pointer for the solution. Something that I tried but did not fully work out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `groupingBy` with `summingDouble` and not `toMap`:

```
Map<String, Double> finalResult = samples
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Sample::getCurrency,
                Collectors.summingDouble(Sample::getAmount)
        ));
```

I consider amount is of type `Double` and your example is not correct (`String amount;`)

Comment: Good answer so +1. However `toMap` works with a third argument of `Double::sum` which I demo'd in my alternative answer.

Comment: nice one @WJS I don't know about it before

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to offer the following alternative for future consideration. I am also presuming you meant `double` for the amount as well as having the appropriate getters. You could have used `Collectors.toMap` as long as you included a `merge function`. It looks like you had the right idea but the wrong syntax.

```
List<Sample> samples =
                List.of(new Sample("USD", 10), new Sample("USD", 30),
                        new Sample("INR", 40), new Sample("INR", 90),
                        new Sample("EUR", 20), new Sample("EUR", 50));
```

The third argument to `toMap` is a `merge function` to properly handle duplicates. In this cases it computes a sum of the values for each key as they are encountered.

```
Map<String, Double> result = samples.stream()
           .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                 Sample::getCurrency, Sample::getAmount, Double::sum));

result.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
EUR=70.0
USD=40.0
INR=130.0
```

If you really want your class to store the amount as a `String`, you can replace `Sample::getAmount` with `sample->Double.valueOf(sample.getAmount())` to convert the `String` to a `Double`.  But since you will probably be using these values repeatedly in computations, it is best, imo, to store the amount in its most frequently used form when the class instances are created.

Answer (score 2):

```
Map<String, Double> finalResult = samples.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(
          (Sample::getCurrency),
          Collectors.summingDouble(
             sample -> { return Double.parseDouble(sample.getAmount()); 
})));
```

Comment: **input** : `( INR 40   USD 80    EUR 20),  (INR 0   USD 100    EUR 100 )` </br>         
**result**     `{EUR=120.0, USD=180.0, INR=40.0}`